# Middle span element with auto width and overflow hidden

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Update: Using flexbox is an option, but a solution that supports legacy browsers would be preferred.

It should be an easy task, but now I am searching for hours for an solution without success. I would like to create an navigation where the middle span "Very long headline 1 2 2 3 4 ..." does not do a line break and grow vertically when the view port size is getting very small. Content that does not fit into the span header-title should be hidden.

For a better understanding I attached two graphics and a jsfiddle example.

Current: 
[image]

Target: 
[image]

jsfiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/herbert_hinterberger/ofu8c8rn/3/

```
<div class="container-fluid">

<div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left">

    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9">
        <div class="row" id="header"> <!--header-->
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <span id="header-menu-trigger" class="pull-left hidden-md hidden-lg" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
                </span>
                <span>
                    <h3 id="header-title">Very long headline 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 </h3>
                </span>
                <span class="notification-container pull-right">
                    <h3 class="notification">8</h3>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div> <!--/header-->
    </div> <!--/offcanvase-->
</div> <!--/row-->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try flex. Flex will ensure that the middle element stretches/shrinks to the available space. Also, remove pull-right on the notification-container div.

https://jsfiddle.net/5s3v55px/

Add this CSS

```
.my-flex{
    display:flex;
}
.flex-1{
    flex:1;
}
```

HTML Changes

```
<div class="col-xs-12 my-flex">
                    <span id="header-menu-trigger" class="pull-left hidden-md hidden-lg" data-toggle="offcanvas">
                        <i class="fa fa-bars fa-3x"></i>
                    </span>
                    <span class="flex-1">
                        <h3 id="header-title">Very long headline 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 </h3>
                    </span>
                    <span class="notification-container">
                        <h3 class="notification">8</h3>
                    </span>
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing this option. The only "downside" seems to be the "poor" support on IE. Therefore I was searching for a solution that works also on legacy browsers. But of course. If it's not available I will follow your suggestion. Thanks

Comment: Just realized that the number of users using IE 9 and lower are really low. Therefore your suggestion seems to me the best option. Many thanks!

Comment: Awesome, glad I could help. Also use flex properties with browser-specific prefixes whenever possible. Some info here https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/.